# iPhone Credit Card Payment

Tags: mobile, pci-dss

I am trying to understand what is the best way to implement a credit card payment flow into a native iPhone app. From what I see on the market, most of the apps use a WebView to process the payment. I haven't found examples of native implementation of it. What are the drawbacks of a native solution? Is either one of these solutions PCI compliant?

Comment: Just use a payment processor like PayPal

Comment: I can't. I need to offer Visa, Mastercard and all the most important circuits for the payment. Moreover, the website doesn't use paypal and that would be a significant difference in the UX.

Answer (score 2):

Using a WebView makes a lot of sense.

- You have to be connected to the Internet anyhow.
- Performance is not an issue.
- There's lots of already written and well tested web-based payment processors.
- Many people (and you specifically) already have a web-based payment processor in place for non-mobile uses.
- More secure since as much as possible is on your servers rather than in the client.
- Apple less likely to demand you use the built-in payment systems (with their cut).

PCI is not really optional, so if someone has a working business based on payment from iPhone via WebView then it's going to be possible to meet PCI.